# formatting displaying data from angularjs

Tags: angularjs

API is connected well and showing display data, now facing the issue of formatting data into table.
using **ng-repeat="item in items"**,
if use in **tr** then only 1 row shows, if using in tbody, then its repeats tbody.

**HTML code**

```
                    <tbody ng-repeat="item in itemsc">
                    <tr >
                        <th width="15%">Country</th>
                        <td width="85%">{{item.name}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Flag</th>
                        <td>
                            <img ng-src="/assets/images/f/{{item.iso2 | lowercase}}.png"  />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Capital</th>
                        <td>{{item.capital}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Region</th>
                        <td>{{item.region}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Region</th>
                        <td>{{item.subRegion}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>GPS</th>
                        <td>Latitude: {{item.latitude}}  |  Longitude: {{item.longitude}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

Keep the data format like this.
**Country,Flag,Catpital,Region,GPS** are static.

```
> ------------------------------- 
|  Country |  Value              |
> -------------------------------
|  Flag |  Value              |
> -------------------------------
|  Catpital |  Value              |
> -------------------------------
|  Region |  Value              |
> -------------------------------
|  GPS |  Value              |
> -------------------------------
```

Comment: Put the `ng-repeat` on the `table` instead

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet added below: Please have a look at **angular code, and way it is implemented in a table**. Cheers.!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  angular.module("todoApp", [])
  .controller("MainController", function($scope){
   $scope.Products = [];
   
   for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
    var app = {
     ProductId: i,
     ProductName: 'ProductName' + (i + 1),
     ProductCategory: 'ProductCategory' + (i + 1)
    };
   
    $scope.Products.push(app);
   }
  });
 </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="todoApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
  <table>
   <tbody ng-repeat="product in Products">
   <tr>
    <td>
     <div style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
      <table border="1" cellpadding="2">
       <tr>
        <td>Sr.No</td>
        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Product Name</td>
        <td>{{product.ProductName}}</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Product Category</td>
        <td>{{product.ProductCategory}}</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Try moving `ng-repeat="item in itemsc"` from `tbody` to `tr`.
This should probably solve your problem.

Ideally the format should be as:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<td>Sr.#</td>
<td>Name</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="prop in Properties">
<td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
<td>{{prop.Name}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: no, then its repeat the tr only, The 'KEY' is static.
only 'Value' is fetching from angularjs function.

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement the easy way to do this is changing the object structure you are passing to the list (itmes)

eg.

```js
[{
  "column1Value": "Country",
  "column2Value": "Value"
}, {
  "column1Value": "Flag",
  "column2Value": "Value"
}, {
  "column1Value": "Capital",
  "column2Value": "Value"
}, {
  "column1Value": "Region",
  "column2Value": "Value"
}, {
  "column1Value": "GPS",
  "column2Value": "Value"
}]
```